# Generalization for a result on vector analysis

Tags: vector-fields, harmonic-functions, electromagnetism

This is inspired in a problem from Griffths's Electromagnetism book (3th edition).

The problem asks us to construct a vector field which is both solenoidal and irrotational (div-free and curl-free) everywhere.

Perhaps the simplest solution are conservative fields with a harmonic potential. That is, suppose $F$ is conservative, then $\exists\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}\ $ such that:
\begin{equation} {F}=\nabla\phi\end{equation}
Then, if $\phi$ is at least $\mathcal{C}^2$, it's trivial that $\nabla\times(\nabla\phi)=0$. The condition for the divergence implies that it's harmonic:
\begin{equation}\nabla\cdot(\nabla\phi)=\nabla^2\phi=0\end{equation}
The problem of course asks for a closed form. This potential yields the condition:
\begin{equation}\phi(x,y,z)=y(x^2-z^2)\end{equation}
And it's easy to see that it has a nice symmetry to it, since you can freely swap the variables and it will still have a zero laplacian. Taking the gradient extracts the answer.

My question here is, is there a more general form for such "symmetric" potentials? There's obviously a lot of scalar fields we can get, but is there a rigorous way of getting then?

Comment: Are you just asking how to construct more harmonic functions?

Comment: Why do you believe that the solution is $y(x^2-z^2)$?  If there is finite energy, then the only harmonic solution is the trivial solution.

Comment: @peek-a-boo pretty much, yeah. Just plugging things in do not seem particularly satisfying.

Comment: @MarkViola Sorry, could you expand upon that? The laplacian for this potential trivially vanishes.

Comment: And that potential results in "infinte" energy since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi \, d^3\vec r=\infty$.  But I asked why you believe that your solution is "the" solution.    There are an infinite number of harmonic functions.

Comment: The vector space of harmonic functions is infinite-dimensional btw. A very simple way to see this is that you can take any holomorphic function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$, and define $\phi(x,y,z)=\text{Re}(f(x+iy))$ for example. You can play similar tricks with any two out of the three variables $(x,y,z)$. This of course doesn’t exhaust all harmonic functions on $\Bbb{R}^3$.